# Show price up to 50% or 1000%

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I have a table: products

```
|products_id | products_price | 
+------------+----------------+
|1           | 0.69           |
|2           | 1.86           |
|3           | 2.73           |
```

and I have a table: specials

```
|products_id | specials_new_products_price | 
+------------+-----------------------------+
|1           | 27.40                       |
|2           | 37.94                       |
|3           | 1.91                        |
```

In my select I need find which products have specials_new_products_price up to 50% or 1000%.

EDIT (from comment):

```
select p.price, s.specials_new_products_price
from products, specials
where s.specials_new_products_price ...
```

Is posible add to query this ((0.69 - 27.4) / 0.69) * 100 and when the result is up to e.g. -50 show me this products

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I find that for my two first products my discount is too hight (-3871%,-1940%) and for my third products is ok (-30%), 
is posible in mysql query show that too hight discounts or it is so complicated and I talk for about 30000 products.

Comment: show us your code so far then please

Comment: select p.price, s.specials_new_products_price from products, specials where s.specials_new_products_price ... , is posible add to query this ((0.69 - 27.4) / 0.69) * 100 and when the result is up to e.g. -50 show me this products

Comment: You can edit the question, code should be in the question not comments, and formatted to be clear. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add your formula into your WHERE clause and turn the hard-coded numbers into field names:

```
select 
  p.products_id,
  p.products_price, 
  s.specials_new_products_price
from 
  products p
  inner join specials s 
    on p.products_id = s.products_id
where 
  ((p.products_price - s.specials_new_products_price) / p.products_price) * 100 < -50
```

P.S. You also forgot to specify a join condition between your tables, I have added that too.